# Finding a specific layer in a Leaflet LayerGroup where layers are polygons

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to define a bunch of Leaflet polygons like this :

```js
var poly = new L.Polygon([
  [10.1840229, 36.8906981],
  [10.1840393, 36.8906669],
  [10.1840989, 36.8906868],
  [10.1840826, 36.890718],
  [10.1840229, 36.8906981]
], {
  'id': 'someId'
});
```

Then I'm grouping those polygons in a GroupLayer like so :

```js
var group = new L.LayerGroup([poly1, poly2, ..., polyn]);
group.addTo(map);
```

Can I find those polygons by Id using group.getLayer() ?
Or do I need to define the layers/polygons differently to be able to do this ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Leaflet assigns it own unique ID to each layer:

```
var marker = new L.Marker(...);
console.log(marker._leaflet_id) // 24

var polygon = new L.Polygon(...);
console.log(polygon._leaflet_id) // 25
```

The `getLayer` method of `L.LayerGroup`, `L.FeatureGroup` and `L.GeoJSON` take those ID's as a parameter:

```
var layerGroup = L.LayerGroup([marker, polygon]);

layerGroup.getLayer(24); // returns the marker
layerGroup.getLayer(25); // returns the polygon
```

You could also easily assign your own ID's:

```
var marker = new L.Marker(...);
marker.id = 'foo';

var polygon = new L.Polygon(...);
polygon.id = 'bar';
```

And then fetch them like this:

```
var layerGroup = L.LayerGroup([marker, polygon]);

layerGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    if (layer.id === 'foo') // it's the marker
    if (layer.id === 'bar') // it's the polygon
});
```

You can easily throw that into a function and include it in `L.LayerGroup`:

```
L.LayerGroup.include({
    customGetLayer: function (id) {
        for (var i in this._layers) {
            if (this._layers[i].id == id) {
               return this._layers[i];
            }
        }
    }
});

var layerGroup = L.LayerGroup([marker, polygon]);

layerGroup.customGetLayer('foo'); // returns the marker
layerGroup.customGetLayer('bar'); // returns the polygon
```

EDIT: Didn't spot the ID in your example untill the indented edit. You can also assign it as an option like in your example and create a custom get function to retreive the layer:

```
L.LayerGroup.include({
    customGetLayer: function (id) {
        for (var i in this._layers) {
            if (this._layers[i].options.id == id) {
               return this._layers[i];
            }
        }
    }
});

var layerGroup = L.LayerGroup([marker, polygon]);

layerGroup.customGetLayer('foo'); // returns the marker
layerGroup.customGetLayer('bar'); // returns the polygon
```

If you ever need to identify the type of a layer you can do so by using instanceof:

> The instanceof operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

```
var layerGroup = L.LayerGroup([marker, polygon]);

layerGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    if (layer instanceof L.Marker) // it's the marker
    if (layer instanceof L.Polygon) // it's the polygon
});
```

But remember when you find yourself making common selections should ideally have put those features in separate layer/featuregroups.

Comment: I'm gonna stick with what you suggested before the edit. It's work ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

The [`getLayer()` method of Layer Group](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-getlayer) expects a very specific ID: the one that is automatically assigned by Leaflet when ["stamping" a layer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#util-stamp) (e.g. using `myId = L.stamp(myLayer)`).

Therefore you would not be able to use pre-defined ID's.

If you can work with ID's defined dynamically (i.e. not known in advance), you could easily record those and use them to retrieve your layers (polygons).

Comment: I still have to use my own IDs for some reason. So the only way around this is through a loop. 
`for (i=0; i<group.getLayers().length; i++) {
    if(group.getLayers()[i].options.id == 'mySpecificId' ) {
        console.log(group.getLayers()[i]) // the layer that I'm looking for
    }` 
But I still wonder if this is a valid layer.

Comment: What do you mean by "wonder if this is a valid layer"? You would probably be interested in iH8's answer (especially the part after the EDIT). Maybe you could also add a default return to cover the case where the specified ID is not within the group (maybe this is the meaning of your wondering?)